# Accordion-group - Item automatically dropped down

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Need help on the following accordion id. Right now it works for the drop down, but when I open the page the first list item is already dropped down. I need to be able to click it and then it goes down. Currently, there is always at least one list item open. Please advise. Thanks!

```
  <ul id="accordion">
                <li class="title" id="cars"></li>
                <li class="content" id="car">


                        <p></p>

                </li>
                <li class="title" id="watc"> </li>
                <li class="content">


                        <p></p>

                </li>
                <li class="title" id="jewe"></li>
                <li class="content">


                            <p></p>

                </li>
                <li class="title" id="meta"></li>
                <li class="content">


                        <p></p>

                </li>


            </ul>
```

Comment: could you provide a fiddle with code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question and if this will help you
In this example ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/WSq3E/)), i propose to you a simple accordion where you can change the amount of text into li element.
When you load the page the accordion is closed.
When you click on li element this animate itself to auto height.
This is just a simple example, I hope it can help you.
If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.
With this solution all jQuery code you need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#accordion li').click(function(){
            var alt=$(this).height()
            if($(this).hasClass('open ok')&&alt>40){$(this).animate({'height':'40px'},1000)}else{
            $(this).addClass('open ok').css({'background-color':'#CCC'})
            var classe=$('li').hasClass('ok')
            if(classe){
                $(this).css({'height':'auto'})
                var auto=$(this).height()
                $(this).height(alt).animate({'height': auto}, 1000);
                $('li').not(this).animate({'height':'40px'},500).removeClass('ok').removeAttr('style')
                }
            }
        })
})
</script>
```